# How to highlight a table row conditionally using Angular16

Tags: angular, angular16

**What I am creating:** When you access the page, there is a table that shows user data (name, last name, email) and two buttons (edit and delete). When the user clicks edit, they go to "mypage../users/id" where they can see more details (address and phone number), and they can edit them.

**My approach:** I am using two different components: 'user-list.component.ts,' which displays the table with data, and 'edit-user.component,' which displays a form with that specific user data using reactive forms to handle the displayed data, which can also be edited.

**What I want:** i want a way When the user clicks the "confirm" button to confirm modifications, automatically go back to the homepage (where there is the table with data) and highlight the row that has been edited.

*I spent more than 20 hours trying different approaches and searching online, but I couldn't find what I want.*

**One of those many approaches i tried:**

*user-list.component.html*

```
  <tr *ngFor="let user of users" [class.highlighted]="isHighlighted(user.id)">
```

*relevant code from user-list.component.ts*

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadUsers();
    this.route.data.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        const typedData = data as { highlightedUserId: number | null };
        this.highlightedUserId = typedData.highlightedUserId;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching route data:', error);
      },
      () => {
        // Additional logic
      }
    );
  }

          isHighlighted(id: number): boolean {
            return this.highlightedUserId === id;
          }
          private highlightUser(id: number) {
            this.highlightedUserId = id;
        
            this.clearHighlightTimeout();
        
            // timeout to remove the highlight after 3 seconds
            this.highlightTimeout = timer(3000).subscribe(() => {
              this.removeHighlight();
            });
          }
        
          private removeHighlight() {
            this.highlightedUserId = null;
          }
          private clearHighlightTimeout() {
          if (this.highlightTimeout) {
           this.highlightTimeout.unsubscribe();
           this.highlightTimeout = undefined;
         }
        }
```

Comment: you are welcome, i will delete my comment since you got it sorted

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be similar to:

```
// edit-user.component.ts
...    
constructor(private router: Router) {}

onClickConfirmButton(): void {
  // save aditing user data
  ...
  
  // go to users list
  extraData: NavigationExtras = {queryParams: {userId: 123123}};
  this.router.navigate(['/users'], { // <- users list uri
      state: { extraData }
  });  
}

// users-list.component.ts
...
constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  // use user id as you need
  this.highlightedUserId = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras?.state?.queryParams?.userId;
}

// users-list.component.html
<tr *ngFor="let user of users" [class.highlighted]="user.id === highlightedUserId">...</tr>
```